# Infinite rage gimmick?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, barbarian

Elemental Kin states

"At 3rd level, whenever the elemental kin takes an amount of energy damage equal to or greater than her barbarian level while raging, she adds 1 to the total number of rounds that she can rage that day."

What stops an Ifriti Barbarian from setting himself on fire, reducing the damage to zero with his resitsance, and effectively gaining infinite rage?

Answer (score 15):

Quoting the description :

> Whenever the elemental kin takes an amount of energy damage equal to or greater than her barbarian level while raging

If your Barbarian does not take damage, it won't benefit from this.

Comment: +1 If you had a source of continuous 1 point of damage as a level 1 barbarian you could continuously rage if you also had a ring of regeneration, but what the hey would a level 1 be doing with an item like that??

Comment: @Rob A Fighter 14/Barbarian 1 might do it, for fun

Comment: Yea, or might do it for the extra Str. Personally, I'd allow him to. It's powerful, sure, but hardly overwhelming even if he weren't using two of the weakest classes in the game, and its not exactly a trivial cost to set up. Even replacing the fighter levels with levels in something that actually enables you to do a fighter's job, I still don't see it being game-breaking. It would be potentially advantageous, but that's not a bad thing in a character-build option.